# Better Approach to hit the api after the interval flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Currently working on home automation app, in which there is the events API that gives me the events if they are triggered. But i want to continuously run the API so that it will track the events that are triggered in the overall application. And there is a home page where i show the events in which ever occured. Its a simple rest APInot web sockets used, Its kind of request response type.  Any suggestions that how can i implement it in a proper way. Currently using the Timer in every page.But this is not a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You would definitely need to use `Timer.periodic()` for period calls. I would suggest you follow this approach.

1. Try to reduce it to only one API call by sending the required data in the same API so you can reduce the network load.
2. Create a common service for fetching the event details by creating parent `BLOC` or `provider` as per your state management implementation.
3. Run the periodic job every 10 sec or depending on your requirement.
4. Don't call the API until the previous API response is fetched. You need to keep a track of it.
5. The response can be reflected on UI after a successful response on all the pages by using the common consumer of the `BLOC` or `Provider` so the code will be modularized and you will be avoiding the duplicate code.
6. Don't forget to dispose of the timer object.

Comment: Just want to ask like I have an API that returns the list of events occured, but the API has a default to wait for 60 Seconds and if in between the event comes it will fetch the data. So my question is like if I set the timer for 60 Seconds and then it hits the API for first time then it will wait for 60 Seconds, and then later hit the API after that. Buy if the event gets triggered in between that 60 Seconds interval . I would not get the event. Any suggestions for this one.

Comment: It's confusing now. Does your server hits another server? Why it's 60 second wait time? Can you explain your API a bit?

Comment: So  the api is like when I trigger any event then, the api has a by default timer of 60 seconds and if any event gets triggered then the api gets list of events  data, but if there is no event getting triggered so it will wait for 60 seconds to check if any event occurred if not then the empty list  will be returned.

Comment: I am not sure how you implemented it in BE but it does not look like an async API call. You just can't keep the connection for 60 seconds for sync call. It's a very bad performance for an API end-point. With the current architecture(May need more info), you probably consider an alternative by just triggering a request and returning the success response after some check and hit another API after 60 seconds to get the result which should be stored by previous request somewhere. You can use some caching mechanism here.

Comment: I need more information about BE API implementation to give more efficient invocation implementation.